# Round decimals of numbers in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, coordinates, rounding

I have a list, each row contains 4 floats (should represent a bounding box)

```
[[7.426758, 47.398349, 7.850835593464796, 47.68617800490421], 
[7.850835593464796, 47.398349, 8.274913186929592, 47.68617800490421], 
[8.274913186929592, 47.398349, 8.698990780394388, 47.68617800490421]]
```

I would like to round each float to 6 decimal places.
I tried to round the numbers using pandas, but it also didn't work.

```
{49: '7.850835593464796,49.12532302942521,8.274913186929592,49.413152034329414', 
17: '7.850835593464796,47.9740070098084,8.274913186929592,48.26183601471261', 
71: '10.395301154253572,49.70098103923361,10.819378747718368,49.988810044137814'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`numpy.around`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around):

```
# lst is your list
np.around(lst, 6).tolist()
```

Output:

```
[[7.426758, 47.398349, 7.850836, 47.686178],
 [7.850836, 47.398349, 8.274913, 47.686178],
 [8.274913, 47.398349, 8.698991, 47.686178]]
```